# Print multiple-line section between two strings only if this section contains certain keyword using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file named `animals` which has following entries:

```
$ cat animals
name: elephant
class: mammal
habitat: India

name: Baltic herring
class: fish
habitat: Baltic sea

name: wolf
class: mammal
habitat: Sweden

name: eagle
class: bird
habitat: USA
$
```

As seen above, this file contains four sections. I would like to print out only those sections which contain string `mammal` and I would like to do this in bash, i.e. not use `sed` or `awk`. I did it like this:

```
$ cat animals | while read -r line; do
>   if [[ "$line" =~ ^name ]]; then
>     section="$line"
>     while read -r line2; do
>       if [[ "$line2" =~ ^$ ]]; then
>         break
>       else
>         section+=$'\n'"$line2"
>       fi
>     done
>   echo "$section" | grep -q mamm && echo "$section"$'\n' ; section=
>   fi
> done
name: elephant
class: mammal
habitat: India

name: wolf
class: mammal
habitat: Sweden

$
```

However, is there a more elegant(shorter and not so cumbersome) way to achieve this in bash? Or is this a point where one should look into tools like `awk` instead?

Comment: You should definitely look into awk. In awk `awk -vRS= '/mammal/' file`. Bash is not made for text processing.

Comment: I see. Is `awk` especially strong in text processing, e.g. rearranging parts of (multiple-line) text, printing multiple-line text if certain conditions are met, etc? Because at least if text is only one line long, `sed` should be able to do anything needed(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should look into awk. It allows you to do this much more simply:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/mammal/' file
```

This unsets the record separator, so that each block is treated as a single record. It then prints each record that matches the pattern "mammal", followed by two newlines, producing the same output as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple,

```
grep mammal -C 1 --group-separator="" animals
```